# Troubleshooting timer delay between Javascript frontend and Python backend

Tags: javascript, python, date

I have a JS frontend app making API calls to a Python backend API. To combat replay-later attacks, every HTTP request from the frontend app has a header with the time of the request (in milliseconds from epoch).

```
headers['request-epoch'] = Date.now()
```

The Python backend also calculates its own current time (in seconds from epoch):

```
dt = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
seconds_from_epoch = int((dt - datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)).total_seconds())
```

Then it compares the difference:

```
request_timestamp = self.request.headers.get('request-timestamp', 0)
request_seconds_from_epoch = int(request_timestamp) / 1000
seconds_elapsed = abs(seconds_from_epoch - request_seconds_from_epoch)
```

Here is the weird thing:

Once is a while, `seconds_elapsed` is **over 60 seconds**, while I am testing the frontend. The interaction on the frontend returns in less than a second, so the request / response is definitely taking less than 60 seconds. Therefore, I am trying to figure out why the timestamp discrepancy is anything more than a second.

It is hard to reproduce, but I a log whenever this happens, which is how I noticed the problem. Any ideas on why this could be happening?

Comment: Maybe that partcicular request is timing out and getting resent after a minute? Except that the value of the timestamp generated by the javascript would not change (it's the same request getting resent).

Comment: Are you sure that client's system time is equal to backend machine? I dont think so. I think that this is error prone approach.. You wont believe to client's timestamp..

Comment: The time on the client machine will vary greatly - and some of them will be misconfigured, looks right, but time zone is wrong, or it is just wrong. If you are to attempt such an approach, you will need to reference the time on the server and use it with the local machine's time to generate an offset that can be used on the form submission.

Comment: Good points. Forgot the that client machine time, even when I force UTC, uses the system clock and can therefore be untrustworthy.